# Need to use javascript to open an existing html document and write to a specific div

Tags: javascript, html, url

I am trying to use javascript to open an existing html document and write to specific div.

I have tried a few things:

```
newwindow=window.open();
newdocument=newwindow.document;
newdocument.write
```

Which opens a new window/document and writes to it but i need it to open a specific file and write to a specific div. Is this possible. I am also playing around with:

```
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML= content
```

I just can't seem to get this - javascript is new to me and I am not sure if i am trying for something that is impossible.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iframe and make the source the html you wish to import.  Or you can use javascript to insert an object tag with the html as source:

```html
<div id="name">
  <iframe src="myPage.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

```js
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="myPage.html" ></object>';
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. I think i probably did not describe this well. iFrames will not work for me in this particular instance. I need to know if javascript can be used to open an existing html file and write to a div within that html file... I tried option #2 above but i don't want to load the existing html file into a div, but into the browser and write to a div within it. thank you in advance..